# Flickity does not render the second image in the carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, flickity

http://codepen.io/Thisisntme/pen/rVRyJE is a test of my website. I am attempting to add a flickity carousel, and for some reason it will not render the second image in the divs.  Here is the carousel without all the other html and css stuff. http://codepen.io/Thisisntme/pen/waOeWa

```
<div class="gallery js-flickity">
   <div class="gallery-cell">
      <img src="https://4c95d0ec6dcefe3d6c4d74191bd78c322c485be4.googledrive.com/host/0Bxf7lERLL3TlfjlMT28zSU9RdUFqZ2ZzWlFyWFpKMzJIbUpBelFIUnlsbTVHVUlfNVJfaXc/ART.JPG" alt="art">
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-cell">
      <img src="https://4c95d0ec6dcefe3d6c4d74191bd78c322c485be4.googledrive.com/host/0Bxf7lERLL3TlfjlMT28zSU9RdUFqZ2ZzWlFyWFpKMzJIbUpBelFIUnlsbTVHVUlfNVJfaXc/STUFF.jpg" alt="stuff">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
   padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
     
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Heres proof the image links are good

[image: art]
[image: stuff]

Oh, and no jQuery.

EDIT: for those of you who still care, the images don't work anymore. Google Drive stopped letting you host from their servers.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in HTML and CSS, please add your JS.

Comment: @AleshaOleg The JS is the imported flickity library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `.gallery-cell` just needed a `width` of `100%`, and at least for me, your `img` tags needed to be explicitly closed. To get around a sizing issue, I explicitly initialized Flickity using JS, instead of implicitly using the HTML class.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3qr6hub1/2/

```js
var flkty = new Flickity('.gallery');
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
   padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.gallery-cell {
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.0.0/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.1.0/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
   <div class="gallery-cell">
       <img src="https://4c95d0ec6dcefe3d6c4d74191bd78c322c485be4.googledrive.com/host/0Bxf7lERLL3TlfjlMT28zSU9RdUFqZ2ZzWlFyWFpKMzJIbUpBelFIUnlsbTVHVUlfNVJfaXc/ART.JPG" alt="art" />
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-cell">
       <img src="https://4c95d0ec6dcefe3d6c4d74191bd78c322c485be4.googledrive.com/host/0Bxf7lERLL3TlfjlMT28zSU9RdUFqZ2ZzWlFyWFpKMzJIbUpBelFIUnlsbTVHVUlfNVJfaXc/STUFF.jpg" alt="stuff" />
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer works... but only when i resize the page. Before the page is resized, the images dont show up and it looks like this  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxf7lERLL3TlSGw3Z1B3cDJoWGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What was your fix? When i copied the code over to my website it still didnt work until resized  http://codepen.io/Thisisntme/pen/rVRyJE

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I ran into this problem as well, leaving this here for when the next Googler comes through. Whenever I added an **image** to the carousel it wouldn't show up.

This is because when the cell is appended the image has not loaded yet. Meaning Flickity takes this cell to have no content, making the `.flickity-viewport` element have a height of `0px`.

So what you need to do is make sure that your item that is being appended is tagged to be **lazyLoaded**. This lets Flickity know that it needs to wait for **imagesLoaded** before parsing the content.

**Example:**

```
myNewCell = '<img src="src.png" data-flickity-lazyload="src.png" />
flkty.append(myNewCell);
```