# flickity only shows first image

Tags: jquery, flickity

I've seen a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909435/flickity-does-not-render-the-second-image-in-the-carousel) of [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919199/carousel-images-are-not-displayed-correctly) around this issue but adding imagesLoaded:true doesn't help.
my code is very simple:

```
var $carousel = $('.carousel').flickity({
            imagesLoaded: true,
  freeScroll: true
});
```

any advise would be appreciated.

see https://theprospecthollywood.com/room/superior/

Answer (score 1):

turns out there was an answer on Stackoverflow already.

```
.carousel-cell { width: 100%; } .flickity-slider img { max-width: none; }
```